# How to handle Data from BluetoothLE Device in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, byte

I have a C# console application that I want to use to read data from a Meadow microcontroller.

I followed these instructions from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client

I have everything working from connecting to the device to getting all services and characteristics only until I need to process the received data / value of my characteristic. Currently I want to read only one Int32.

This is my Bluetooth characteristic:

```
intCharacteristic = new CharacteristicInt32(
                name: "My Number",
                uuid: "017e99d6-8a61-11eb-8dcd-0242ac1300bb",
                permissions: CharacteristicPermission.Write | CharacteristicPermission.Read,
                properties: CharacteristicProperty.Write | CharacteristicProperty.Read
                );
```

How i set its value:

```
int testInt = 111;
intCharacteristic.SetValue(testInt);
```

This is part of my console application:

```
    GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync();
if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(result.Value);
    byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
    reader.ReadBytes(input);
    
    //This is where i am stuck, I tried the following but it does not return my actual integer
    int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(input, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
}
```

input array includes the following:

```
[0] = 248
[1] = 255
[2] = 253
[3] = 63
```

How to i get the actual integer from those Bytes? I get an Integer that has nothing to do with the original one

Comment: How many bytes do you receive? How is the BLE device formatting the value before transmission?

Comment: I receive 4 Bytes, those get stored in the input array.  

I am not quite sure about the formatting, documentation about the Device is very poor since Meadow is still in Beta phase. 


result.value is a System._ComObject.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add a set of expected and actually received values?

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: These values are weird... Have you tested to read the value using a generic BLE scanner such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: i just installed the app you recommended. The app returns following Value for my characteristic: (0x) F8-FF-FD-3F.

Comment: Yeah this is the same value, just represented as Hex values. I just don't get how `111` can result in such a value

Comment: Yeah, me neither. I first thought I was handling the received data incorrectly in my console app, but since the nRF Connect app returns the same value, I'm a little confused.

Comment: I would recommend taking a better look at the microcontroller code. Maybe you could add more of it to your question

Comment: tbh there is not much more relevant code for the microcontroller. I followed the Bluetooth guide from Wilderness Labs, the manufacturer of the microcontroller. You can check it out here: http://developer.wildernesslabs.co/Meadow/Meadow.OS/Bluetooth/